# Bootstrap: How to apply mobile-toggle to navbars without navbar-default?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my navbar set up like this: (note the class is `navbar navbar-default`)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-global">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-global">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav topnav">
        ....
```

This works fine, and I get the sandwich menu to the right of the screen.

I want to be able to apply the same CSS behavior for `navbar` but without the `navbar-default` class. But If I do:

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
```

my sandwich menu doesn't display at all.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap adds a background color to the toggle menu when you add the class navbar-default:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #888;
}
```

when removing the class, there is no background color applied, so you need to add it youtself

```
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {

  // background-color:*****;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just paste the below **css** in your custom css file which will be situated just below your bootstrap css file

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-global">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-global">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav topnav"></ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```